# packageInfo.versionCode always return 1

Tags: android

If I change Manifest.xml's versionCode from 1 to 2, packageInfo.versionCode always returns 1.
I want to return 2, where should I fix?
incidentally packageInfo.versionName returns 1.0 in this case.

```
PackageManager packageManager=getContext().getPackageManager();
        try{
            PackageInfo packageInfo=packageManager.getPackageInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            DB_VERSION=packageInfo.versionCode;
            Log.v("a"," "+packageInfo.versionCode);
            Log.v("b"," "+packageInfo.versionName);
        }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
PackageInfo packageInfo=packageManager.getPackageInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
```

to

```
 PackageInfo packageInfo=packageManager.getPackageInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), 0);
```

Comment: I changed PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES to 0, but versionCode in Logcat was still 1.

Comment: Is getContext().getPackageNAme() giving same package as in Manifest?

Comment: My Manifest.xml's package is same as in package name of top of Java file. if meaning of my answer is wrong , sorry.

Answer (score 8):

You are probably using gradle.
If you are using gradle you should change the version code in gradle.build not in Androidmanifest.xml